# How do you handle authentication in a base box?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I build a base box that I can use and am hosting it on a local share. I am able to add it locally with 'box add ', and I can then 'vagrant init '. Thats all good.

However, I can't seem to get the authentication working. The base box has the vagrant keys on it (from https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/keys) and has a user/pass of vagrant/vagrant. I can get authentication working if I add the following to the Vagrantfile

```
vm.ssh.username = "vagrant"
vm.ssh.password = "vagrant"
```

However, I dont want to have to add that to my Vagrantfile each time. I tried adding that to the Vagrantfile in the .box file, but that didnt do it either.

What am I missing about setting up a base box?

Edit: my ssh-config

```
brian@brian-mbp:~/Dev/vagrant/banking$ vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2201
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/brian/Dropbox/dev/vagrant/banking/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

Comment: What is the output of `vagrant ssh-config` ?

Comment: I added it to my post

Comment: And [this](file://home/brian/Dropbox/dev/vagrant/banking/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key) is the same as [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant)?